# Adding dynamically checked checkboxes values to a list

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm displaying a list of preference as checkboxes, the problem reside in the binding part where i want a list of the ids that were checked.
my try who does not work:

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let preference of preferences">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="{{preference.id}}" (change)="preferencesStates[i]=$event.target.value">{{preference.label}}</label>
</div>
```

This is how i bring the preferences:

```
this.reservationService.getPreferences().subscribe(preferences => {
  if (preferences) {
    JSON.parse(preferences.body).forEach(element => {
      this.preferences.push(element);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: how did you get the ids?

Comment: from a list brought by restful service.

Comment: post the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `(change)` event you can bind a function like this -

```
(change)="getInput($event)"
```

I would prefer to pass the index as well.

Now in your component class add the following code:

```
public resArray: any[] = [];  //for storing the checked ids

getInput(event: any,index:number) {
   if(event.target.checked){
      this.resArray.push(event.target.value);
    }else{
      this.resArray.splice(index,1);
    }
  }
```

Note here that you get both the `checked` and `unchecked` conditions.

Now the `resArray` will contain all the ids that were checked. Make sure you pass the index. So, your template code will look like this -

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let preference of preferences;let i=index">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="{{preference.id}}" (change)="getInput($event, i)">{{preference.label}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: then you can modify the getInput function signature to this in your template - `getInput(id, $event.target.checked)` and in your component class - `getInput(id:number, isChecked:boolean)`

Comment: the index start by 1 not 0 it makes the first value in my array at undefined

Comment: You can add condition to insert element in your array only if `index > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code with this

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let preference of preferences; let i = index;">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="{{preference.id}}" (change)="preferencesStates[i]=$event.target.value">{{preference.label}}</label>
</div>
```

In this `i` is not defined anywhere , `preferencesStates[i]`

**Another solution :**

```
<div class="checkbox" *ngFor="let preference of preferences; let i = index;">
<label><input type="checkbox" value="{{preference.id}}" (change)="preferencesStates[preference.id]=$event.target.checked">{{preference.label}}</label>
</div>
```

Declare it as `preferencesStates:any;` in your component , this will give you list of all preferencesStates with id , checked as true and unchecked as false.

Comment: OK, works but I still got an issue before closing this, when unchecking the checkbox the id resides in the list even thought I unchecked..

Comment: Try another solution , if it still not satisfy please let me know